# Seeking summary of 39 melachos

Tags: halacha, jewish-books

Seeking a summary of the practical application of the 39 melachos, organized by melacha.  Preferably something much shorter than Rabbi Ribiat's 3 volume set.  Ideally, available on the web. (English preferred.) Suggestions?

Comment: The Shabbos Kitchen/Shabbos Home books by Rav Simcha Bunim Cohen are significantly smaller than that of the Ribiat set. Maybe check that out?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shabbat) (Halachipedia) looks good - scroll down for the 39 melachos.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sefer with color photographs of all the melachot. It discusses the source for the melacha, Avot and Tuldot, and brings practical modern examples of those melachot.

I have the hebrew version, and they have an english version, which you can see [here](http://www.judaicaenterprises.com/Product.asp?dept=1026&Product=bk-ib-l141). (If anyone can find a better link, feel free to add it)

The English version is titled: "[The Book of Shabbos (With color Photographs of the Melachos)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0057ZPJEU)"